# how to pause activity until service is stopped?

Tags: android, service, camera, android-activity

Here is my code. I want to call same `CameraService` two time inside `for` loop

```
for (int camIdx = 0; camIdx < cameraCount; camIdx++) {
    Camera.getCameraInfo(camIdx, cameraInfo);
    if (cameraInfo.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
        try {
            Intent camIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),CameraService.class);   //calling service first time
            camIntent.putExtra("camNum", camIdx);
            startService(camIntent);
        } catch (RuntimeException e) { 
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else if (cameraInfo.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK) {
        try {
            Intent camIntent = new Intent(
getApplicationContext(),CameraService.class);  //calling service first time
            camIntent.putExtra("camNum", camIdx);
            startService(camIntent);
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I want to pause my activity when service is running, otherwise my activity will call `cameraService` again while service is already running. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Holy cow! Have you ever heard about indentation?

Comment: I don't think you're approaching the problem correctly.  Have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9527728/prevent-multiple-copies-of-an-android-service)

Answer (score 0):

you need to add a listener ,i added some sample code.Follow this it must be helpfull.

```
service.SearchEmployee(searchStr, Offset, NO_OF_ITEM_IN_PAGE, onlyManager, new IRequestListener<List<Employee>>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onRequestFailed(String message) {

                                Toast.makeText(getContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                requestCompleted = true;


                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onRequestCompleted(List<Employee> data) {

                                if (Offset == 1)
                                    cacheMap.put(searchStr, data);

                                tempList = data;
                                requestCompleted = true;
                                lock.notifyAll();
                            }

                    });
```

Comment: i am calling service inside for loop, how can i use listener..?

Comment: call service seperately..or run that one with AsynTask or cacheBackground function. On that you implement the customized listener.