# Android service not ending, but sleeping. Restarts when a new instance is created resulting in two services

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service

I am working on an Android project that requires me to end a service completely and then restart it at some later time. It should end when a user logs out and restart when the user logs in.

I am new to the project and Android, so sorry if this question will have an obvious answer.

The service extends IntentService. I override onDestroy and in this method I call stopSelf() and I also call stopService(intent) where the intent is the intent passed to onStartCommand. The main service has some other services that are bound to it, but I make sure to unbind them (I think I have found all of them) before calling the stop functions.

When the user logs out, it appears that the service is dead. There are no log messages coming out and the app just hangs, as expected. When I log back in, there are two services running. I can tell this because the log messages are printing doubles (triples if I log out again and log back in, quadruples if I do it again, and so on). For example, there's a message that says "Starting service" in the onHandleIntent

What reasons could cause the service to restart in duplicates? Could it be a bound service that I missed?

Thanks.

Comment: I suggest showing some actual code. It will help determine the problem.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9527728/prevent-multiple-copies-of-an-android-service

Comment: Calling `stopSelf()` and `stopService()` in `onDestroy()` is useless. If `onDestroy()` is called, the `Service` is already stopped.

Comment: Android does not start more than one instance of a `Service`. Services are singletons by definition.

Comment: Hi, I didn't know there was a difference between IntentService and Service, but I think the question not very useful now because it wasn't a service I was working with. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue I was having was that the service was an IntentService. Instead of killing the service and restarting it, I just change parameters while it runs.